# React project running on same server as node client routing

Tags: server, routes, client

My project directory structure is implement in a way that the frontend dir sits inside the main dir where `index.js` of server file lives.
The problem is when I try to route to a specific page on client `/about` for example.
The call will be made to the server and not to client. on the home page `/` the server sends the call to `/frontend/build/index.js`. How can I achieve the same result to other routes?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was routes order on the `index.js` file of server

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).